Why is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a x^2 + 5 x +11}{6 x + 7} = \pm \infty$ for positive and negative $a$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$?
I was told that if we solve
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {a x^2 + 5 x + 11}{6 x + 7}$$
We get $+\infty$ for positive $a$ and $-\infty$ for negative $a$ and I don't understand why as if we follow the standard procedure and divide both terms with $x^2$, we get
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a + \frac {5}{x} + \frac{11}{x^2}}{\frac{6}{x} + \frac{7}{x^2}}$$
If we put the limit we get, $\frac{a}{0}$ which to my knowledge should be not defined as it is a definite number divided by zero but that is not case. Why is there such a difference when in every other case this expression should be not defined?
Please help me understand why we use $\pm \infty $ here instead of not defined.

All that shows is your method failed.  How i introduced that method was to divide by the highest power of $x$ in the denominator.  Here, that means you divide by $x$, not $x^2$.

If $a\ne0$, $\frac a0$ is not undefined. It is $\pm\infty$. More precisely, if e.g. $a>0$, then $\frac a{0^+}=+\infty$, $\frac a{0^-}=-\infty$.

@AnneBauvel isn't $\frac {1}{0}$ undefined because the function of $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches two different values from two directions at x= 0?

@BrainMoehring Ah! I see. So by this method the ultimate expression we get is merely $\frac{a\infty + 5}{6}$  and here a determines the sign of $\infty$

Please see the precision in my previous comment. It applies here because your $\frac a0$ is actually $\frac a{0^+}$ because as $x$ tends to $\infty$ (i.e. $+\infty$), $6/x$ tends to $0$ by positive values. P.s. your notifications are not received when you misspell the names.

Aah! Thank you. I understand.

Even when you write:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

you are actually writing that the limit "does not exist". You are giving extra information too, that it does not exist for a particular reason that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily large and stays that large for ever onward as opposed to less specific ways that a limit can fail to exist.
So this limit being $\pm\infty$ is not incompatible with your arithmetic that led to an undefined expression.

By the way, since $x\to+\infty$, the expression in your denominator is approaching zero from above, from the positive side of zero. So $\frac{a}{\text{tiny positive number}}=\text{huge number with the same sign as $a$}$, and this is again compatible with what you expected.

Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell me why we don't use this logic or how is this logic different for $\frac{1}{x}$ when x approaches 0

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x$ also does not exist. It also fails to exist in a particular way that is interesting enough to warrant special notation "$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x=\infty$". I don't see it as any different.

isn't $\frac{1}{0}$
undefined because the function of $\frac{1}{x}$
approaches two different values from two directions at x= 0?

No. $1/0$ is undefined because it asks you to divide $1$ by $0$. And with standard arithmetic there simply is no prescribed meaning to that action. It's more fundamental than anything having to do with functions.

To clarify your first comment responding to OP, do you make a distinction between $\infty$ and $+\infty$?  Without such a distinction, we would typically say $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1x$ doesn't exist even as an extended real number, as $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1x = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac1x = -\infty$.  I believe this is the distinction OP intended, even as they misattributed the reason $1/0$ is undefined to it.  (While $\lim{x\to0} \frac1x = \infty$ is true in the one-point compactification, this would be a bit exotic for most students)_

@BrianMoehring Sorry, I had a one-sided limit in mind. I'm not sure if I'd add to the confusion if I tried to clear it up here now.

The numerator approaches $a$, which we will suppose to be non-zero.
The denominator approches zeros, by positive value, meaning it approaches zero, yet is always strictly positive, but it gets smaller, and smaller.
For your intuition, $\dfrac{1}{0.01} = 100$, $\dfrac{1}{0.0000001} = 1 000 000$, the smaller the denominator, the bigger the number. And that should seem natural, $\dfrac{1}{b} * b =1 $, so if $b$, (the denominator), is very small, $\dfrac{1}{b}$, which is the amount of time you should add $b$ to itself to get $1$, should be, well, big.
For you problem, the denominator is small, very small, yet positive, so if $a$ is positive, then it will approach $+\infty$, while if $a$ is negative, it will approach $-\infty$. This is the standard rule, positive times positive is positive, and positive times negative is negative.
